# how to filter in firebase using javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

below is my javascript code snippet, it responds showing all admin databases,taufik,nanarsih,,,I want to get the database value with admin key, how do I do that?

```
<script type="module">
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import {
    initializeApp
} from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.11/firebase-app.js";
import {
    getAnalytics
} from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.11/firebase-analytics.js";
import {
    getDatabase,
    ref,
    onValue,
    equalTo
} from "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/firebase/9.6.11/firebase-database.min.js";

// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "123",
    authDomain: "123",
    databaseURL: "123",
    projectId: "123",
    storageBucket: "123",
    messagingSenderId: "123",
    appId: "123",
    measurementId: "123"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
const db = getDatabase(app);

onValue(ref(db), (snapshot) => {
    const data = snapshot.val();
    console.log(data);
});
```

[image: In firebase]

this is the response in the console log:

```
{admin: 123, nanarsih: 123, taufik: 123}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To just get the `admin` vaue from the database, you can create a reference to that path and then read that:

```
const adminRef = ref(db, 'admin');
onValue(adminRef, (snapshot) => {
    const data = snapshot.val();
    console.log(data);
});
```